# python string substitution in sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm trying to use an IN statement to return results which match one of a list of strings

for example

`strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']`
`c.execute('select count(*) from table where foo in ?', strings)`

i know this is incorrect and doesnt work but i hope that it highlights what im trying to do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that. There are three problems:

- You can't have a table called `table` unless you use backticks around the table name.
- An IN clause must have parentheses.
- You want three parameters, not one.

Try this instead:

```
sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE foo IN (?, ?, ?)'
```

If the number of strings is variable, use this instead:

```
params = ','.join('?' for x in strings)
sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE foo IN (' + params + ')'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `','.join(strings)` as @Mark Byers suggests, that works most times. However if the number of strings is **very long** it will fail because SQL queries have bounded length.

Another way of doing it is creating a temp table, inserting there all the strings and doing a join to perform the intersection, something like

```
c.execute('CREATE TEMP TABLE strings (s STRING)')
c.executemany('INSERT INTO strings (s) VALUES (?)', ((s,) for s in strings))
c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table JOIN strings ON table.foo == strings.s')
```